# Adding WPF ListView Items Dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm looking for examples or help to create a WPF listview of files.

```
<ListView Margin="10,10,0,13" Name="ListView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="200">
```

I Load my files with this method :

```
    private void AddFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string[] filePath = ofd.FileNames;
            string[] safeFilePath = ofd.SafeFileNames;
        }
    }
```

What should I do now ?

ListView1.Items.Add(...) don't seems to work. In fact I can't find ListView1 from my cs code.

I found info [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFListView09092008224322PM/WPFListView.aspx)

Comment: do you want to show all files in a folder or only files selected by the user one by one? what is your end result?

Comment: The problem is not about loading the files. My problem concern adding something to a listview.

Comment: About the name, try x:Name instead of Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use DataBinding for display items in ListView
you should bind the ObservableColliction files;
with your ListView ItemSource property
and when you add or remove files in collection on the ListView items will be updated automaticaly

for example look at this [article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1)

Answer (score 1):

Simple,

- Store your file(name)s in a list (ObservableCollection) in your ViewModel
- Databind the ListView.ItemSource to that collection
- Add/Remove/Change files in the Collection, not in the Listview

If you're not using an explicit ViewModel, use your WindowClass as such.

Answer (score 1):

as a quick and dirty way you can assign the collection of files directly to the ItemsSource property of the ListView

```
ListView1.ItemsSource = safeFilePath;
```

in the XAML you can add an ItemTemplate to customize the visualization of the single files